# How to make a recursive treeview collapsible

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css, treeview

I have a recursive treeview which pulls all its information from a database and would like some insight as to how I can make it collapsible.
I tried using Jquery and Javascript but neither attempt had any effect. Not sure if was maybe just error on my part or something else.

here is my basic code:

```
<body>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
mysql_select_db('test');


 $qry="SELECT * FROM treeview_items";
 $result=mysql_query($qry);


 $arrayCategories = array();

 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
 $arrayCategories[$row['id']] = array("parent_id" => $row['parent_id'], "name" =>                       
 $row['title']);   
  }
//createTree($arrayCategories, 0);

 function createTree($array, $currentParent, $currLevel = 0, $prevLevel = -1) {

foreach ($array as $categoryId => $category) {

if ($currentParent == $category['parent_id']) {                       

    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) echo " <ul> "; 

    if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li> ";

    echo '<li id="'.$categoryId.'" onclick=child(this.id);>       
 <span>'.$category['name'].'</span>';

    if ($currLevel > $prevLevel) { $prevLevel = $currLevel; }

    $currLevel++; 

    createTree ($array, $categoryId, $currLevel, $prevLevel);

    $currLevel--;               
    }   

}

if ($currLevel == $prevLevel) echo " </li>  </ul> ";

}   
?>
<div id="content" class="general-style1">
<?php
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=0)
 {
?>
<ul>
<li id="0" class="root"><span>Categories</span>
<?php createTree($arrayCategories, 0); ?>
</li>
</ul>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it really worth to take a look at this css only approach for collapsible tree views: http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu With a few modifications it can be used for any kind of tree view that you might want to use.

Comment: CSS hadn't even crossed my mind for it, I'll look into it thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find a working collapsible tree view, made using php and jQuery.

It works like a charm (Except that I need to make a pre-collapsed treeView..but maybe you don't need that, in which case, this should solve your problem)

[How to make pre-collapsed TreeView with php/javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349533/how-to-make-pre-collapsed-treeview-with-php-javascript)